# How can I put One Input file of data in one Reducer and another input file data in another reducer

Tags: hadoop

I have two text file lets say file1.txt in which I have written all the capital letter word ,another one file name is file2.txt ,in which I have written all the small letter word ,so how can I do this input split for all the capital letter of file1.txt in one reducer and all the small letter of file2.txt in diffrent reducer.

can any one please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

```
create custom partitionser.
```

The main purpose of partitioner is partitions the key,value pairs of mapper output intermediate keys,The partitioner will divided the data based on our user defined conditions,which works like a hash function.The total number of partitions is equal to total number of reducers in a job. ( job.setNumReduceTasks(n)) . The partitioner phase takes place after the map phase and before the reduce phase in our mapreduce program.The default partitioning function is the hash partitioning function where the hashing is done on the key. However it might be useful to partition the data according to some other function of the key or the value.

```
  //Set number of reducer tasks in drive program
   job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
```

then create custom partitioner class and add the logic for partition the map data on the bases of Upper/lower case of data value.

```
public static class customPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,Text>{
        public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks){
        if(StringUtils.isAllUpperCase(value))
            return 0;
                else
            return 1;
}
```

For example of custom partitioner -> http://www.hadooptpoint.org/hadoop-custom-partitioner-in-mapreduce-example/

Comment: Thanks a lot Kishor Kumar Suthar to help me out of this problem

Comment: @MohitMIshra plz, accept the answer if the answer is right so that other StackOverflow user will not find difficulty to do the same thing.